# What do the partition flags mean during Debian installation?

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

When installing Debian 9.3, the partition part of the install shows a table like

```
SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdc) - 160.0 GB ATA HDDNAME
    >   #1  primary 524.3 MB        B       ext4
    >   #2  primary 159.5 GB            K   lvm
```

What do the flags mean?  "B" indicates a boot partition, but I've also seen "K", "F", and "f", with no indication anywhere I can find of what these are supposed to mean.

Comment: Debian doesn't require / doesn't use flags.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing a bit with this and as far as I can tell the latter column has to do with what debian plans to do with the partitions during set up.  "F" and "f" are various kinds of format and "K" I believe means keep.  GNU parted, cfdisk, sfdisk, gparted, and fdisk do not use these flags. When you toggle on and off the options of formatting and erasing within the setup GUI these flags seem to toggle as well.

However, I did not inspect the installer's source code. So there's strong, but not direct evidence for this to be correct.